# Im confused on why did my prof. put height as -14m on this question. can someone explain?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, reference-frames, coordinate-systems, free-fall

The question is

> A snowball rolls off a barn roof that slopes downward at an angle of $40^\circ$ The edge of the roof is 14.0 m above the ground, and the snowball has a speed of $7.00\ \mathrm{ m/s}$ as it rolls off the roof. Ignore air resistance.

My prof. want to find the time and he set up it up as $-14= -4.5t-4.9t^2$ . I'm confused on where did the $-14$ come from I thought the final is $+ 14\ \mathrm m$.

when I use Chegg they set it up as $14= 4.5t+4.9t^2$ but I am also confused on why is the gravity positive.

Comment: Isn't the final height 14 metres *below* the initial height?

Comment: Your professor set the reference point on the roof, and not on the ground. Hence every distance below the reference point is negative by convention. What Chegg does is make the ground the reference, hence everything positive.  Remember you get to choose signs as long as you are consistent through with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signs don't matter. As long as they fit together internally, they could be any. That's because you can set up your reference frame, your coordinate system, in any way you want.

Just remember how the original motion equation looks,

$$s=s_0+v_0 t+\frac12 a t^2,$$

and then simply input the values with signs according to whichever coordinate system you are referring to.

- Place the coordinate system with its origin at the roof edge and with the y-axis pointing upwards. Then the downwards speed is negative, the downwards gravitational acceleration is negative, the initial position is zero and the final position is below the zero point and thus negative.
- But place the coordinate system still with the origin at the roof edge but with the y-axis pointing *downwards* instead, and then all those numbers become positive (the speed is in the positive direction, your final position is further along this axis than the starting point etc.)

The most intuitive choice might be the former. But there really is no issue in choosing any. Just always remember that signs have no physical meaning. They only indicate direction *relative to a chosen reference frame or coordinate system* which you choose freely.

In other words: you theoretically can't be given an answer to a question like this without also being told the choice of coordinate system.

Comment: why is the orgin at the roof and not the ground?

Comment: @gosdavid Choosing the origin of the coordinate system is just as arbitrary as choosing the coordinate axis direction. It's a free choice. Had the origin been chosen to be at the ground with and upwards y-axis, then the *initial* position would have been 14 m rather than zero, and the *final* position would have been 0 rather than 14 m: $$0=14\,\mathrm{m}-4.5\,\mathrm{m/s} \cdot t-4.9\,\mathrm{m/s^2}\cdot t^2. $$ But if you plug that into the equation and rearrange slightly, then it turns out to become the same equation and result as before.

Comment: @DJohnM You are right. I honestly don't know why I wrote it with minus signs...

Answer (score 1):

It is just a matter of choice of signs. Your professor considered the edge of the roof as the datum and made the measurements from there considering the downward direction to be negative. The person who solved the question on Chegg considered the downward direction as positive.

Comment: why is the orgin at the roof and not the ground? If the origin is at the ground then y initial = 0 and y final = 14 and accelration =-9.8

Comment: No, then the $y$ initial is 14 and the $y$ final is 0.